# Firebase Android cannot enter in the addOnCompleteListener after create an user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

after 2 days in this bug i had to post this question, i am creating a database as it appears in my cadastrarUsuario method. The problem is, after passing the line "createUserWithEmalandPassword" and creating the user in the firebaseAuthentication(i checked that in the browser) it just crashes. the console says:

```
05-05 06:36:48.895 4791-4834/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
05-05 06:36:48.895 4791-4834/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
05-05 06:36:48.912 4791-6318/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui V/FA: Activity paused, time: 2141000
05-05 06:36:48.936 4791-4791/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui V/FA: onActivityCreated
05-05 06:36:48.957 4791-6318/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2141044
05-05 06:36:49.122 4791-4791/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
05-05 06:36:50.541 4791-4805/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( Onec4KwKzUUMA5mXualVJSovhum1 ).
05-05 06:36:50.541 4791-4791/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
05-05 06:36:50.542 4791-4791/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
05-05 06:36:59.008 4791-4834/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
 05-05 06:37:13.445 4791-6318/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui V/FA: Activity paused, time: 2165532
05-05 06:37:13.460 4791-6318/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 2165547
05-05 06:37:13.626 4791-4791/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
```

> > UPDATING ERROR
> >     IT APPEARS IN THE CONSOLE NOW

"05-05 07:34:38.011 24936-24967/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

> > AND HERE IS MY ACTIVITY  (with the error in cadastrarUsuario method)

```
package studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;

import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.helper.Base64Decoder;
import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.helper.FirebaseConfig;
import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.helper.Preferences;
import studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui.helper.User;

/**
 * Created by bruno on 24/04/2017.
 */

public class CadastroActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button cadastrar;
    private EditText email;
    private EditText nome;
    private EditText senha;
    private EditText senhaConfirm;
    private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
    private DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase;
    public User usuario;
    private Base64Decoder decoder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro);

        nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadastro_nome);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadastro_email);
        senha = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadastro_senha);
        senhaConfirm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.cadastro_senhaConfirm);

        cadastrar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonValidarCadstro);

        cadastrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                usuario = new User();
                usuario.setName(nome.getText().toString());
                usuario.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
                usuario.setSenha(senha.getText().toString());
                System.out.println("EMAIL: " + usuario.getEmail() + "SENHA: " + usuario.getSenha());
                cadastrarUsuario();
                startActivity(new Intent(CadastroActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        });

    }

    private void cadastrarUsuario() {

        autenticacao = FirebaseConfig.getFirebaseAuthentication();

        System.out.println("EMAIL: " + usuario.getEmail() + "  SENHA: " + usuario.getSenha());

        autenticacao.createUserWithEmailAndPassword("getRripped2@hotmail.com", "superm34tboy"
            ).addOnCompleteListener(CadastroActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                           // FirebaseUser usuarioFireBase = task.getResult().getUser();
                            String idUser = Base64Decoder.encoderBase64(usuario.getEmail());
                            System.out.println("BASE64 ENCODER: " + idUser);
                            usuario.setId(idUser);
                            usuario.save();

                            /*firebaseDatabase = FirebaseConfig.getFireBase();1

                            firebaseDatabase.child("usuarios").setValue(idUser);*/

                            firebaseDatabase = FirebaseConfig.getFireBase();
                            firebaseDatabase.child("pontos").setValue("300");

                            FirebaseUser usuarioFirebase = task.getResult().getUser();
                            usuario.setId( usuarioFirebase.getUid() );

                            Preferences preferences = new Preferences(CadastroActivity.this);

                            preferences.saveData(idUser);

                            /*autenticacao.signOut();*/
                            Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Usuario cadastrado com sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            finish();

                        } else {

                            try {

                                System.out.println("TASK ERROR CARAIO " + task.getException().toString());
                                throw task.getException();

                            } catch (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Senha invalida, favor escolher outra senha para autenticacao", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException e) {
                                Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "e-mail invalido, verifique os valores digitados", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                System.out.println("ERROR CARAIO " + e);
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

        );

    }
}
```

Here is my build gradle info:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "studio.brunocasamassa.ajudaaqui"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}



repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {


    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4+'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.rtoshiro.mflibrary:mflibrary:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:23.1.1'
    compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.3.6@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your play services version is higher than 9.
- Enable authentication using email/password in the firebase console.
- Update your firebase libraries to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be from your Google Play Services version. Have you check it? Before that, please take a look at the [offical doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#prerequisites).

Also, be sure you have an Android device that is running `Google Play Services 9.0.0` or later. Check `The Google Play Services SDK` from the `Android SDK Manager`.

Is your Android Studio 1.5 or higher?

Check also the `Android Studio Project` and its `package name` to be correct.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i just did that, checked the google play services and it is not that the problem, the package name issue i did'nt know how to check it,